# How to stop text from wrapping around image when using nl2br? overflow:hidden doesn't work here

Tags: php, css, nl2br

I am designing a comment frame for a webpage I am working on. Upon using **nl2br** to ensure line-breaks aren't removed from stuff submitted from the the  in the form, **the text just wraps around the user image** in the comment section (please see image). **overflow:hidden doesn't work here**. How to handle this?

A screenshot of the comment frame.
[image]

```
<div class="comment_section" style="overflow:hidden";>
    <a href="<?php echo $posted_by?>" target="_parent"><img src="<?php echo $user_obj->getProfilePic();?>" title="<?php echo $posted_by;?>" style="float:left;" height="30"></a>
    <a href="<?php echo $posted_by?>" target="_parent"><b><?php echo $user_obj->getFirstAndLastName();?></b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <?php echo $time_message . "<br>" . nl2br($comment_body);?>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Disable float left

Comment: This hasn't helped I have tried it in the past: 
a) It will push the picture up top, and 
b) overflow: hidden; will still not work to stop the text from wrapping.

Comment: Put the comment inside a container like ‘div’ and put the float left on the div.

Comment: Please add the generated HTML (not the PHP that generates it) and the related CSS so we can see the issue directly on the question. Read about how to create a [mcve] for more information.